# SWI-Prolog xml_write to variable

Tags: xml, swi-prolog

How do I `xml_write` to a variable instead of a stream?

I've tried this:

```
current_output(O),
with_output_to(string(X),
               xml_write(O,[element(table, [style="width:50%"],
                           [element(tr, [span = 2],
                           [element(td, [], ['First name']),
                            element(td, [], ['Last name'])])])],
                           [header(false)])).
```

But the above still outputs to output stream and moreover, doesn't unify `X` with anything. Here is the output:

```
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr span="2">
    <td>First name</td>
    <td>Last name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
O = <stream>(6D342F30),
X = "".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [xml_write/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=xml_write/3) which has signature:

```
xml_write(+Stream, +Term, +Options)
```

in order to effectively write to a stream. However, since you're rather looking to unify the resulting XML with a variable, have a look at [xml_write/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sgml_write%3Asgml_write/2) which looks like:

```
xml_write(+Data, +Options) is det
```

Using this in your code, it could look something like:

```
xml_output(X) :-
    table(Out),
    with_output_to(string(X),
                   xml_write(Out,[header(false)])
                  ),
    writeln(X).

table(R) :-
    R = [element(table, [style="width:50%"],
        [element(tr, [span = 2],
        [element(td, [], ['First name']),
         element(td, [], ['Last name'])])])].
```

Example query:

```
?- xml_output(R).
   <table style="width:50%">
     <tr span="2">
       <td>First name</td>
       <td>Last name</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   R = "<table style=\"width:50%\">\n  <tr span=\"2\">\n    <td>First name</td>\n    <td>Last name</td>\n  </tr>\n</table>".
```